# How to change background color of 'code definition' window in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, ide

see title for question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Open Tools->Options->Fonts and Color. Change the background color of the text editor and all text tool windows."

There is however a bug there :

"I have changed the background color for the code definition window in VS2008. However, when I close VS and open it again, the background color returns to the default color."

Response from microsoft :

"
Thank you for reporting this bug. We didn't discover it in time to fix it for Beta1, but you should see it fixed for the next release of VS 2010."

Link to the error report and a patch that will fix the problem [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=454578).

Comment: so - it's fixed only for VS2010?

Comment: That is the impression that I get when reading that error report, that it still isn't fixed in 2010 beta1 but will be fixed in next release of 2010.

Comment: In case you're still on VS2008. Old question, but it seems fixed for me (perhaps in the service pack or hotfixes). I'm able to retain the change to the code definition window's background color between restarts of VS2008.

Comment: Note: 2014, and a fully patched Visual Studio 2010 Pro still looks like a joke; it's as if  Microsoft make promises about fixing bugs but never quite get around to it in their quest to bring out the next version of Visual Studio.   Why does this window a) behave differently to all the other windows, and b) is next to inconfigurable?

Answer (score 0):

- On you current install, go to `Tools` | `Import and Export Settings`.
- Choose `Export selected environment` settings and click next.
- Click the top box to remove the check box from everything.
- Expand `All Settings` | `Options` | `Environment`.
- Click to check the box next to `Fonts and Colors`
- Click Next and save your file
- Restart IDE